# Automating DDL in .Net

Tags: .net, sql, dynamic, ddl

I maintain a product that has a home-grown data access layer, programmed in C++/COM for use with a Windows-based web application designer and it is at least 10 years old. This DAL is modularized with something akin to Data Providers so that it can generate basic SQL and DDL for a specific database type.

In the process of migration analysis, the biggest gap in functionality I have found is with the DDL generation. With the current product, the user creates/deletes data input forms and then data input fields and the appropriate database tables and fields are created or deleted "on the fly" (fields cannot be altered). Foreign key relationships are "soft" however, only enforced at the code level.

Through my research so far, it seems that this approach is not highly regarded for security and data integrity reasons. Which is probably the reason I can't find any tools/ORMs that have the same functionality.

I have experimented with nHibernate, which contains half of what I need with it's SchemaUpdate functionality but only does non-destructive schema updates. I have checked out other ways of dealing with a dynamic schema such as xml columns, but this greatly complicates other factors like data retrieval and reporting.

**My questions ares fairly large in scope, so I am not looking for definite answers, only pointers. What are the options for continuing forward with this approach? Are there better options for allowing a dynamic schema that I am not aware of? What are the basic advantages and pitfalls of other possible approaches?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged this question ".net", plus you say you have experimented with nHibernate, so I'm making the leap to assume that you are trying to migrate toward .NET and away from COM.  I am also guessing that you are running Microsoft SQL Server, though there is no specific reason that this *must* be the case (soft foreign key enforcement was historically a MySQL "feature," for example).

Entity Framework can probably help you as far as a data access layer goes generally, but you will run into the same sorts of restrictions.  What you possibly could do, though, is go ahead with the XML-based approach you were mentioning and extend the data models by way of partial classes that work alongside the Entity Framework classes.  You could, then, write methods that would retrieve particular pseudo-fields from the XML column and return them, helping your data access layer to be more-or-less separated from the rest of your application.

That said, I would take a good look at your data modeling and see whether this dynamic approach is really even necessary.  What kinds of data are you storing?  Could you handle it through, say, [Complex Type Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) in Entity Framework 4?  I'm pretty sure that a fresh look at the data modeling and business requirements of your application will yield a way to do something more normalized than a dynamic schema.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are correct, the migration would be to .Net and away from COM. The existing product supports Access, MsSQL and Oracle. 

This project has been more or less cancelled and the existing product is just being left to rot. I never did find a satisfactory solution with existing toolsets. If the project ever did go ahead again, I imagine I would end up going with a home-grown ORM-like(or perhaps only dataset-based) solution that used "pluggable" dialect classes for SQL and DDL generation (exactly like nHibernate in that respect).

Answer (score 0):

I am too faced with similar dilemma of migrating changes done on development environment to staging and then production.
The application(s) I am dealing with demands frequent modification and soon after last role-up it is time for next.
If you are in SQL 2005 or above, you are in better place.. 
Here is what I have come up with.
Implement a DDL Trigger on your source database that tracks and log DDL statements into seperate database in the Server instance such as:

```
    Create trigger [DDLTRack]
ON Database for

CREATE_ASSEMBLY         ,ALTER_ASSEMBLY         ,DROP_ASSEMBLY
,CREATE_ASYMMETRIC_KEY  ,ALTER_ASYMMETRIC_KEY   ,DROP_ASYMMETRIC_KEY
                        --,ALTER_AUTHORIZATION
                        ,ALTER_AUTHORIZATION_DATABASE 
,CREATE_CERTIFICATE     ,ALTER_CERTIFICATE      ,DROP_CERTIFICATE
,CREATE_CONTRACT                                ,DROP_CONTRACT          
--,ADD_COUNTER_SIGNATURE                            
--,DROP_COUNTER_SIGNATURE
--,CREATE_CREDENTIAL        ,ALTER_CREDENTIAL       ,DROP_CREDENTIAL
                                                                ,GRANT_DATABASE ,DENY_DATABASE  ,REVOKE_DATABASE
,CREATE_DEFAULT                                 ,DROP_DEFAULT
                                                                ,BIND_DEFAULT   --,UNBIND_DEFAULT   
,CREATE_EVENT_NOTIFICATION                      ,DROP_EVENT_NOTIFICATION
,CREATE_EXTENDED_PROPERTY   --,ALTER_EXTENDED_PROPERTY  
,DROP_EXTENDED_PROPERTY  
,CREATE_FULLTEXT_CATALOG    ,ALTER_FULLTEXT_CATALOG ,DROP_FULLTEXT_CATALOG  
--,CREATE_FULLTEXT_INDEX        ,ALTER_FULLTEXT_INDEX   ,DROP_FULLTEXT_INDEX 
,CREATE_FUNCTION            ,ALTER_FUNCTION         ,DROP_FUNCTION
--,CREATE_INDEX             ,ALTER_INDEX            ,DROP_INDEX
--,CREATE_MASTER_KEY            ,ALTER_MASTER_KEY       ,DROP_MASTER_KEY
,CREATE_MESSAGE_TYPE        ,ALTER_MESSAGE_TYPE     ,DROP_MESSAGE_TYPE
,CREATE_PARTITION_FUNCTION  ,ALTER_PARTITION_FUNCTION   ,DROP_PARTITION_FUNCTION
,CREATE_PARTITION_SCHEME    ,ALTER_PARTITION_SCHEME     ,DROP_PARTITION_SCHEME
,CREATE_PLAN_GUIDE          ,ALTER_PLAN_GUIDE           ,DROP_PLAN_GUIDE 
,CREATE_PROCEDURE           ,ALTER_PROCEDURE            ,DROP_PROCEDURE
,CREATE_QUEUE               ,ALTER_QUEUE                ,DROP_QUEUE
,CREATE_REMOTE_SERVICE_BINDING  ,ALTER_REMOTE_SERVICE_BINDING   ,DROP_REMOTE_SERVICE_BINDING
--,CREATE_SPATIAL_INDEX                                                                 
--  ,RENAME   
,CREATE_ROLE                ,ALTER_ROLE                 ,DROP_ROLE  
--,ADD_ROLE_MEMBER                                      ,DROP_ROLE_MEMBER
,CREATE_ROUTE               ,ALTER_ROUTE                ,DROP_ROUTE
,CREATE_RULE                                            ,DROP_RULE              
                                                                                            ,BIND_RULE  ,UNBIND_RULE 
,CREATE_SCHEMA              ,ALTER_SCHEMA               ,DROP_SCHEMA
,CREATE_SERVICE             ,ALTER_SERVICE              ,DROP_SERVICE
--,ALTER_SERVICE_MASTER_KEY                 
--,BACKUP_SERVICE_MASTER_KEY    
--,RESTORE_SERVICE_MASTER_KEY
--,ADD_SIGNATURE                                            ,DROP_SIGNATURE

--,CREATE_STATISTICS                                        ,DROP_STATISTICS                    ,UPDATE_STATISTICS
--,CREATE_SYMMETRIC_KEY     ,ALTER_SYMMETRIC_KEY        ,DROP_SYMMETRIC_KEY
,CREATE_SYNONYM                                         ,DROP_SYNONYM
,CREATE_TABLE               ,ALTER_TABLE                ,DROP_TABLE
,CREATE_TRIGGER             ,ALTER_TRIGGER              ,DROP_TRIGGER
,CREATE_TYPE                                            ,DROP_TYPE
,CREATE_USER                ,ALTER_USER                 ,DROP_USER 
,CREATE_VIEW                ,ALTER_VIEW                 ,DROP_VIEW
,CREATE_XML_INDEX           
,CREATE_XML_SCHEMA_COLLECTION   ,ALTER_XML_SCHEMA_COLLECTION    ,DROP_XML_SCHEMA_COLLECTION


as 
insert ddlTracking..ddlLog(TSQL,SchemaName,ObjectName,ObjectType,eventXML,LoginName,dbName,EventType)
Select EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,EVENTDATA()
       ,EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(max)')






GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

DISABLE TRIGGER [DDLTRack] ON DATABASE
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [DDLTRack] ON DATABASE
GO
```

This will i all your changes

in (this case) DDlTrack.dbo.DDLlog table..
You can then group last modification done to a database object by sifting the required entries in the Source database and apply them to the Target.
HTH.